# How to autodecrement timestamp in database?

Tags: php

Is there a way to autodecrement a timestamp stored in database second by second?

Example take timestamp=60 and after 1 minute timestamp should be 0 in database.
How to store such a timestamp in database and decrement time

Comment: There are ways; though every second is going to put a very heavy load on your server; but most people would simply calculate the new value when requested

Comment: Without knowing much else about your use case, a better approach might be to consider storing the future expiration date.  Then when you receive a request compute the delta of now and that date (that way you don't have to update the database).  This is analogous to how we commonly store a person's birthdate to dynamically calculate their age.